# Can't connect to minikube external service or ingress

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, kubectl, minikube

I have clean ubuntu 18.04 server where installed minikube, kubectl and docker.

And I have several items for it.
One deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-express
          image: mongo-express
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-db-secret
                  key: mongo-db-root-username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-db-secret
                  key: mongo-db-root-password
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-db-configmap
                  key: mongo-db-url
```

one internal service. because tried to connect through ingress

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
```

one ingress for it

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: "Prefix"
            backend:
              service:
                name: mongo-express-service
                port:
                  number: 8081
```

And one external service because I tried to connect through them

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-external-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30000
```

But each of these options does not work for me. I tried add update to host file and add
`192.168.47.2 my-host.com`
but it also didn't help me.
When I run `curl my-host.com` in server terminal I receive correct response, but I can't get it from my browser.
My domain set up to my server and when I use nginx only all work fine.
May be need to add something else or update my config?
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: The latest version that I can install to ubuntu 18.04